# Is it legal to write a check that will bounce and leave it in a public place?

Tags: united-states, oregon

John Doe, who has $50 in his checking account, write a check to CASH for $1,000,000 and signed it, then left the check in a public place. Jane Smith tried to deposit it, and it bounced. Did John do anything illegal? Can Jane sue him for the money?

Comment: This question is a good example of why courts don't issue advisory opinions.

Comment: Anything that causes a discussion like this one - which is a lot of fun - the advice would be "don't do it". Is it a crime to give a judge a headache? You're surely guilty of that if it goes to court :-)

Comment: @gnasher729 actually, it is: Contempt of court can be given for anything that annoys the judge - from wearing annoying clothes to talking too much or in a voice that gives the judge headaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description it seems that Joe abandoned the check (and didn't lose it, or gave it to Jane as a present, or for payment), so anyone finding it can pick it up and keep it.

If I abandon a wallet with 10,000 dollars in fake banknotes, can I be sued for the money? Obviously the faked banknotes might get me into trouble, but I don’t think I’d owe the finder $10,000. That might be quite close to the question.

I could argue that a finder of abandoned things gets exactly what they found, could be a broken bicycle (worth repairing or not), could be a crime novel with the last page ripped out, in this case a check over a million that is worth nothing because nobody will pay out for it.

Or I might have written the check to pay a debt to Joe, Joes bank manager just laughed, so Joe threw the check away in a public place. For extra fun, imagine I win a million in the lottery and it gets put into my account…

I’d recommend not doing that kind of thing to avoid trouble for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

### Jane committed a crime

No matter if the check was valid, **it wasn't Jane's check**. "Finders keepers" is **not** good law. By trying to cash it immediately, jane committed at least one crime and might also have committed forgery (by filling in her name as the recipient).

It also claimed to be a high enough value that in [germany](/questions/tagged/germany), Jane would be obligated to go to the police and declare the found item - **Anything** worth more than 10 € is to be declared that way because keeping a found item is "Unterschlagung" after [§246 StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__246.html) and for "low value items" (the 10 € limit) it requires the owner to request prosecution under [§248a](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__248a.html).

Only after declaring the found item, Jane can get entitled to anything of the check: if the real owner is found and can prove it is his, then Jane is entitled to 3% or 5% of the real value of the check - 5% for 500€ and below, 3% for above. But in this case, the real value of the check is nothing and so there is no Finderlohn: even if it presents to be more, it is worth noting. However, since it is a check, the one writing it can be trivially located by police and bank, meaning that the owner is easily found... and the real value as "nothing" found out.

Only after a waiting period of 6 months after declaring the found item the check would become her property. Only now Jane might have claim to the money the check presents to be worth - but the police will have found John as the previous clear owner by then and brought him back his check.

### When Jane isn't entitled to the money, she can't sue.

A person is not entitled to the proceeds of a crime. As a result, she can't sue for the money.

Comment: According to the description, the check was not lost but abandoned. If it was lost, then the situation is quite trivial. In the USA, Jane can either ignore the check (not pick it up), or pick it up and look for the legitimate owner, which should be easy since their name and bank details would be on the check.

Comment: @gnasher729 the main point is: that finding it doesn't make jane the owner, and even if the check was abandoned, she doesn't become the owner by finding but, under many laws, has to make earnest attempts to locate the owner.

Answer (score -1):

> Did John do anything illegal?

No (apart from littering).

> Can Jane sue him for the money?

Yes. She can file a lawsuit, pay the court fees — only to get laughed out of the courtroom.

Answer (score -2):

### Yes

Knowingly writing a check that has insufficient funds is a crime. For example, in [Texas](https://www.afullerlaw.com/blog/2020/06/when-writing-a-check-becomes-a-crime/), it can be a misdemeanour or a felony.

Jane can sue for the money because a check is not just a piece of paper, it’s a promise by John to pay the bearer of the check.

Now, a court may not smile on Jane’s suit because she doesn’t appear to have acted honestly here but remember a check is a negotiable instrument. Let’s assume Jane owes her banker, Jenny (to keep the J theme going), $1,000,000 and uses the check to pay for it. Now Jenny may be foolish for accepting it (because she has substituted John’s credit worthiness for Jane’s) but it is a perfectly legal transaction - checks can circulate from person to person just like cash - that’s what negotiable means. Now as a completely innocent person, the court is much more likely to support Jenny’s claim against John: bankruptcy awaits.

Comment: Knowingly writing bad check is only a crime when it is used to obtain some benefits / defraud the check recipient. That's what the linked Texas law says in a nut shell. Nothing of the kind that John did.

Comment: @Greendrake and how has Jenny not been defrauded here?

Comment: By way of neither John getting anything out of it, nor Jane being entitled to any enrichment or losing anything.

Comment: On top of that, there is simply no mens rea in John's action.

Comment: The actual Texas law does not mention fraud. "(a) A person commits an offense if he issues or passes a check or similar sight order for the payment of money knowing that the issuer does not have sufficient funds in or on deposit with the bank or other drawee for the payment in full of the check or order as well as all other checks or orders outstanding at the time of issuance." Texas Penal Code - PENAL § 32.41

Comment: @JerryCoffin The keywords are "for the payment of money". No need to mention fraud literally.

Comment: @Greendrake: Maybe. Or maybe "for payment of money" is just descriptive--that is, the thing written is "a check or similar sight order for the payment of money". If there were a comma: "check or similar sight order, for the payment of money", it would be clear that "for the payment of money" is describing what the person is doing rather than the thing being written. Would need a relevant ruling to be sure, but at least at first glance, none showed up.

Comment: This answer is quite wrong, for all the reasons Greendrake has listed. Further, one does not "issue or pass" a check by just writing it out; he must actually present it to someone -- typically as payment for good or services.

Comment: @DaleM: Jenny has been defrauded by Jane, who paid using a negotiable instrument that she knew or a reasonable person would have known was not hers.

Comment: If the check was abandoned then the check is hers. She can frame it and hang it up on her wall. Whether she has any right to the million dollars is another question.

Comment: I'm not sure that a check that is abandoned as opposed to delivered comes within the scope of the statutes on bad checks. It's a weird, unlitigated fact pattern.

Comment: Now if the check hangs on Jane's wall, and two years later she reads in the newspaper that Joe Doe won 10 million in the lottery, could / should the bank pay out the check to Jane if there is a million in the account?